# Hiding menu items in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a program that automatically generates a tree. It looks like

```
<li class="linamesystem">Alternator</li>
   <ul class="boxfornamegroupsparts">
      <li class="linamegroup"><a href="#top(1)">Alternator2</a></li>
      <li class="linamegroup"><a href="#top(2)">Krmilnik alternatorja (regler)</a></li>
  </ul>

Alternator -> Alternator2
           ->Krmilnik
```

What would be the css code for hovering Alternator parent and showing `linamegroup` childs?

Or should I do it with javascript?

Comment: The HTML is invalid (the `li` is closed before the opening `ul`) but I assume that's not in your actual code...right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be CSS rules to use:

```
.boxfornamegroupsparts {
   display: none;
}

.linamesystem:hover + .boxfornamegroupsparts {
    display: block;
}
```

EDIT: as pointed by **Paulie_D**, this is invalid HTML markup, `ul` cannot/shouldn't be direct child of other `ul` element.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is just a piece of code that you have. The real one should be something like this:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li>
   <ul>
     <li></li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Anyway to achieve what you wanna do, just use this css:

```
.linamesystem:hover .boxfornamegroupsparts {
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a similar [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tuqbcq2/1/) for you, illustrating a horizontal menu with submenus. The trick is to initially hide **linamegroup** and display it when **linamesystem** is hovered.

```
.linamegroup { display: none;}

.linamesystem:hover .linamegroup { display: block; }
```